# Running "compass watch" in Foundation 5 returns deprecation warnings

Tags: gruntjs, watch, compass, zurb-foundation-5

Running a grunt compass watch gives me deprecation warnings.

The following is the error log in my terminal:

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "source/sass/layout/_navigation.scss" changed.
Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
DEPRECATION WARNING on line 275 of /Users/username/Sites/sitename/www/projectname/bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_global.scss:
    Assigning to global variable "$default-float" by default is deprecated.
    In future versions of Sass, this will create a new local variable.
    If you want to assign to the global variable, use "$default-float: left !global" instead.
    Note that this will be incompatible with Sass 3.2.

    DEPRECATION WARNING on line 276 of /Users/username/Sites/sitename/www/projectname/bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_global.scss:
    Assigning to global variable "$opposite-direction" by default is deprecated.
    In future versions of Sass, this will create a new local variable.
    If you want to assign to the global variable, use "$opposite-direction: right !global" instead.
    Note that this will be incompatible with Sass 3.2.

    DEPRECATION WARNING: The return value of index() will change from "false" to
    "null" in future versions of Sass. For compatibility, avoid using "== false" on
    the return value. For example, instead of "@if index(...) == false", just write
    "@if not index(...)".
            on line  of /Users/username/Sites/sitename/www/projectname/bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/_functions.scss, in `exports'
            from line 342 of /Users/username/Sites/sitename/www/projectname/bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_global.scss
            from line 5 of /Users/username/Sites/sitename/www/projectname/bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_grid.scss
            from line 103 of /Users/username/Sites/sitename/www/projectname/source/sass/style.scss
        write development/includes/css/mercutio.css (2.757s)

    Done, without errors.
```

Does this mean that I have to update a certain npm package or is this in the foundation framework?

---

Edit: Running compass v1.0.1 by the way:

```
→ compass -v
Compass 1.0.1 (Polaris)
Copyright (c) 2008-2015 Chris Eppstein
Released under the MIT License.
Compass is charityware.
Please make a tax deductable donation for a worthy cause: http://umdf.org/compass
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Seems that my sass was outdated. Was on 3.3 (Maptastic Maple) and should be on 3.4 (Selective Steve).

Run

`$ sass -v`

to find out what your version is. If it's older than 3.4 run a

`$ sudo gem install sass`

to install a new version.